# Cause of periodic jumps in loss function

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training, loss-function, object-detection

I might be missing something obvious as I am new to machine learning. I am training an SSD Inception V2 for detecting buildings from satellite images. I use the Tensorflow Object Detection API. I am having troubles interpreting why the value of loss seems to change periodically:

[image: loss]

Please let me know if I need to add more information

Comment: Please provide more details about your model training. What hyperparameters you specified, batch size, optimization, etc. At the moment we don't have enough information to help you

Comment: Yes, please provide some more info about your data, model, and training hyperparameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be feeding training data in a very specific way or weights and biases reset after a specific period of time, e.g. end of epoch?

I would start with checking that

- training and validation sets consist of a desired class ratio
- datapoints within mini batches are being shuffled
- model parameters are being correctly updated during training